# Python vs MATLAB: ARIMA Model with Known Parameter Values

Tags: python, r, statistics, statsmodels

In MATLAB, we can specify an ARIMA(p, D, q) model with known parameter values by using the following function

[image]

```
tdist = struct('Name','t','DoF',10);
model = arima('Constant',0.4,'AR',{0.8,-0.3},'MA',0.5,...
                        'D',1,'Distribution',tdist,'Variance',0.15)
```

In Python or R, Can I do this to build my own model?

After that, I need use this model to predict my dataset

[image]

In Python or R, Can I do this?

Comment: type `help("arima")` in R. It has a `predict` method.

Comment: Python: Build model(http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/generated/statsmodels.tsa.arima_model.ARIMA.html) and predict(http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/generated/statsmodels.tsa.arima_model.ARIMA.predict.html#statsmodels.tsa.arima_model.ARIMA.predict) with your params.

Comment: When you build model you have to choose the order parameter (lag) and after fit() the result is the model that contains coefficients, However, we can't choose own coefficients to build model @su79eu7k

Comment: In python, you can choose anything if you want. Please check the answer below. @TùngKiềuVũThanh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python StatsModels example below.

In.

```
test_model = sm.tsa.ARIMA(test_data['log_PI'], [1, 1, 0]).fit()
test_model.params
```

Out.

```
const             0.001166
ar.L1.D.log_PI    0.593834
dtype: float64
```

In.

```
_ = test_model.plot_predict(end="2016-12")
```

Out.

[image]

In.

```
# Constant param change
test_model.params.const = 0.02
# test_model.params[0] = 0.02

# AR params change
# test_model.params[1] = 0.9
# test_model.arparams[0] = 0.9

_ = test_model.plot_predict(end="2016-12")
```

Out.

[image]

Comment: That mean we must fit() at least one time before change its parameter

Comment: Hi @su79eu7k, How to change ar_L1 value?

Comment: Hi @TùngKiềuVũThanh, try this way; `test_model.params[1] = 0.9` or `test_model.arparams[0] = 0.9`

Comment: Thanks @su79eu7k . Can I have your email? because I cannot post "ask question" anymore